# How to sniff https?

Tags: networking, https

I've been using Windows for a long time with the HTTP Analyzer application, which is basically Wireshark for http/https protocols and is able to actually process https requests the same way as HTTP.

Now I'm using Wireshark in Ubuntu, but it doesn't capture the HTTPS traffic, which is expected but not convenient. I guess the windows app was somehow hooking to the lower level OS events of decrypting the HTTPS response - is there something of this kind for Ubuntu?

Comment: You can't sniff https traffic without having the server's private certificate.

Comment: @psusi, I'm not sure which way this stuff works, but I am positive that I could do this thing in Windows. I want to sniff my own https traffic, to which I have access through browser

Comment: No, the communications are encrypted with the public key for the server, and  can't be decrypted without the private key, which only the server has. That's the whole point of cryptography :)

Comment: er, of course, the response back from the server also needs to be decrypted by the local system, for which you *have* the private keys. So kindly ignore my previous, dumb comment.

Comment: Your subject line implies you are unable to see the https traffic, which I don't believe is actually the case. Please clarify: You see the traffic, but it is encrypted and unreadable, correct?

Comment: @Wolfger, yes  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you're using Wireshark: Here is their [wiki page on SSL traffic](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL).